# Symfony 4 login form with security and database users

Tags: authentication, symfony4

I was a total noob on Symfony about a week ago and I thought I should just dive in Symfony 4. After a week of trying to solve the basic login problem, I believe the documentation is still missing some parts.

Now I've found a solution and I will share it along with some tips on what you might be doing wrong. First part of the answer is a list of suggestions, while the second part is the creation of a project with working login from scratch (supposing you already have composer installed and using a server like apache).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Part 1: Suggestions

**403 Forbidden**

Check the `access_control:` key in security.yaml. The order of the rules has impact, since no more than one rule will match each time. Keep most specific rules on top.

**login_check**

Make sure the form action sends you to the `login_check` path, or whatever you changed it to in *security.yaml*.

Also check that you have declared a route for the `login_check` path either in a controller or in *routes.yaml*.

**input name**

Symfony forms tend to encapsulate input names in an array, while it only expects them to be named `_username` and `_password` (you can change that in *security.yaml*) to count it as a login attempt. So inspect the inputs to make sure the name attributes are correct.

## Part 2: Full Symfony 4 Login

### Project Setup

Let's start by creating the project. Open cmd/terminal and go to the folder you want to contain the project folder.

```
cd .../MyProjects
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
cd my-project
```

Now you have created a Symfony 4 website template in *.../MyProjects/my-project* and the cmd/terminal is in that path and will execute the rest of the commands properly.

Check in your *.../MyProjects/my-project/public* folder for a .htaccess file. If it exists you are fine, else run the following command.

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

You can now find your site by visiting *my-project.dev/public*. If you want to remove this public path, you should do so using the *.htaccess* file, not moving the *index.php*.

### Project Settings

1) Edit the `DATABASE_URL` key inside the *.env* file to correspond to your database settings.

2) Edit the *config/packages/security.yaml* file, so it looks like this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        user:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            provider: user
            form_login:
                #login_path: login
                #check_path: login_check
                default_target_path: homepage
                #username_parameter: _username
                #password_parameter: _password
            logout:
                #path:   /logout
                #target: /
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/,      roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**Some explanation:**

`App\Entity\User` is the User entity you 'll create in a while to handle the login.

The `user` provider is just a name that needs to have a match in providers and firewalls.

The `logout` key must be declared if you want to allow the user to... well, logout.

Values in `#comment` reveal the default value we'll be using later on and act as a reference of what you are more likely to change.

### User Entity

A user must have a role, but could have more. So let's build a `UserRole` Entity first for a ManyToMany relationship.

```
php bin/console make:entity userRole
```

All entities start with an id property. Add a `role` too.

```
php bin/console make:entity user
```

User needs the `username`, `password` and `roles` properties, but you can add more.

Let's edit the *src/Entity/User.php* file:

Add the `UserInterface` interface to your `User` class.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
class User implements UserInterface
```

Edit the generated `getRoles()`, to make it return string array.

```
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles->toArray();
    foreach($roles as $k => $v) {
        $roles[$k] = $v->getRole();
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

`getSalt()` and `eraseCredentials()` are functions to implement the `UserInterface` interface.

```
public function getSalt()
{
    return null;
}
public function eraseCredentials()
{
}
```

Using the `bcrypt` algorithm (as we set in *security.yaml*) we don't need a salt. It generates automatically one. No, you don't store this salt anywhere and yes, it will produce different hash for the same password every time. But yes, it will work somehow (magic...).

If you need a different algorithm, that uses salt, you need to add a `salt` property on the `User` entity.

### Homepage

For testing purposes we will create a homepage

```
php bin/console make:controller homepage
```

Edit the generated *src/Controller/HomepageController.php* file to change the root to */*

```
@Route("/", name="homepage")
```

### Login Controller

```
php bin/console make:controller login
```

Edit the generated *src/Controller/LoginController.php* file to make it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use App\Form\LoginType;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function index(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        $form = $this->createForm(LoginType::class);
        return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
            'form'          => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */
    public function logout() {}

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
     */
    public function login_check() {}
}
```

### Login Form

```
php bin/console make:form login
```

You don't have to associate it to the `User` entity.

Edit the generated *src/Form/LoginType.php* file to add this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
```

replace this:

```
$builder
    ->add('_username')
    ->add('_password', PasswordType::class)
    ->add('login', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Login'])
;
```

and add this function, to prevent Symfony from changing the input names you requested above by enclosing them in `login[...]`

```
public function getBlockPrefix() {}
```

### Login Template

Edit the *templates/login/index.html.twig* file to add this code in the `{% block body %} ... {% endblock %}`:

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('login_check'), 'method': 'POST'}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

### Database Generation

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

This should have generated your database, according to your `User` and `UserRole` entities.

### Generate Password

The following command will provide you with a hashed password you can directly insert into the database. The password will be hashed with the algorithm specified in *security.yaml*.

```
php bin/console security:encode-password my-password
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, the documentation lacks some important things, but this works very good. For others, check the order of the access-control entries, because one misplaced entry may block the whole process.

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This was working, but this not

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```