# Doctrine generate/migrate command doesn't make tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am learning **symfony** and wanted to make a login page. So I followed this tutorial -[Symfony 4 login form with security and database users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082673/symfony-4-login-form-with-security-and-database-users) exactly the same.

The issue I am having is the `doctrine:generate` and `doctrine:migrate` command.

When I run the command, it does not make the tables. When I check the database with **phpmyadmin**, all I see is a `migration_versions` table and no tables for the entities I created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `doctrine:migrations:generate` command will create an *empty* migration file. You still have to write the sql necessary to create your tables.

The `doctrine:migrations:diff` command will check the database structure against your model classes and generate the sql for you.